# Iterate through a list passed to the class

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure my title matches exactly the issue I'm facing.

The class takes a list of URLs. Methods then process the URL (status_code, WhoIs). However, my issue is that I have difficulties iterating through the list. Even though there are multiple URLs in the list the iteration always uses the first one in the list.

How could you re-write process method so it would pass the correct element in the list to other methods?

Best,
Matija

```
class Whois:
    
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url = url # This is a list of URLs ['http://google.com','http://cnn.com']
        
    
    def who_is(self):
        params = {'apiKey':whois_api,'domainName':self.extract_domain,'outputFormat':'JSON','thinWhois':1}
        parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        base_url = f'https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?{parameters}'
        response = requests.get(url=base_url).json() 
        return response['WhoisRecord']['registryData'].get('expiresDate',None)
    
    def check_host(self):
        r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        if r.status_code in range(200,299):
            return r.status_code
        else:
            raise 'Error'
    
    def process(self):
        Data = collections.namedtuple('Site', 'domain expiry_date status_code')
        processed_data = list()
        for site in self.url:
            processed_data.append(Data(domain=self.extract_domain, expiry_date=self.who_is(), status_code=self.check_host()))
        return processed_data
    
    @property
    def extract_domain(self):
        res = get_tld(url, as_object=True)
        domain = res.fld
        return domain
```

Comment: I think you want use next(self.url).....

Comment: @Janith why? It's a list

Comment: for iterating or def __next__(self) method....

Comment: Matija would you be able to post a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Janith next is used for iterators not iterables

Comment: Most of your methods are referring to an undefined variable named `url` - they seem to be expecting it to be a single URL, rather than a list, so I don't think these are just mistyped references to `self.url`.  Where is that value supposed to come from?

Comment: @jasonharper I pass a list to the class (awkwardly named) - self.url is therefore a list of multiple URLs. `Whois.process()` should return a list containing namedtuples with processed data of all URLs initiated via `payload = Whois(['http://google.com','https://cnn.com','https://medium.com'])`

Answer (score 0):

```py
Data = collections.namedtuple('Site', 'domain expiry_date status_code')
headers = {}

class Whois:
    
    def __init__(self, url_list):
        self.url_list = url_list # This is a list of URLs ['http://google.com','http://cnn.com']
        
    @classmethod
    def get_expires_date(cls, url):
        params = {
            'apiKey':whois_api,
            'domainName':cls.extract_domain(url),
            'outputFormat':'JSON',
            'thinWhois':1}
        parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        base_url = f'https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?{parameters}'
        response = requests.get(url=base_url).json() 
        return response['WhoisRecord']['registryData'].get('expiresDate',None)
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_status_code_2xx(url):
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if r.status_code in range(200,299):
            return r.status_code
        else:
            raise 'Error'
    
    def process(self):
        processed_data = list()
        for url in self.url_list:
            processed_data.append(Data(
                domain=self.extract_domain(url),
                expiry_date=self.get_expires_date(url),
                status_code=self.get_status_code_2xx(url)))
        return processed_data
    
    @staticmethod
    def extract_domain(url):
        res = get_tld(url, as_object=True)
        domain = res.fld
        return domain
```